# Rounding using Math.Round

Tags: c#

I wanted to know whether there is a way to use the Math.Round function in order to convert the value: 0.05 cents to just 5cents? I know I can do this by just multiplying the value by 100, but I do not want to do this as the values are stored within an array and ruins other my calculations when executing other functions.

For example, If the the value is less than 1 dollar, I would then like to print out the cent value without it being a decimal, please refer to the code below:

```
double[] coins = {0.05,0.10,0.20,0.50,1.00,2.00};

Console.WriteLine("Change is as follows:");
        for (int j = 0; j < change_given.Length; j++)
        {
            if (change_given[j] == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (coins[j] < 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} x {1}c", change_given[j], coins[j]);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} x ${1}", change_given[j], coins[j]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the type of the values in the array? Are they number types or string types? I can't tell from your question

Comment: Sorry, they number types. Coin values are stored as doubles within the array.

Comment: that doesn't make any sense.  How would .05 round to 5?  Show us your code, and there is probably a different, better solution

Comment: is this only for display purposes? what is wrong with multiplying by 100 to display the value in the format you want?

Comment: Updated questions with code above.

Comment: Answered my own question. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like this is just for display purposes.  If you multiply `coins[j]*100` you aren't updating coins[j]:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < change_given.Length; j++)
    {
        if (change_given[j] == 0)            
            continue;            
        if (coins[j] < 1)
            Console.WriteLine("{0} x {1}c", change_given[j], coins[j]*100);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("{0} x ${1}", change_given[j], coins[j]);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I just done this and it works. I was having a complete mind blank. Left the computer for a while and returned, now solved.

Comment: @Maff and you did it with Math.Round? How?

Comment: @Jake, I did not do it with Math.Round. Considering it was for display purposes, I multiplied the value by 100. As seen in Jonesy's code above.

Comment: Maff, remember you aren't *assigning* anything unless you are using the return value of something on the left side of a statement : `coins[j] = coins[j]*100`

Comment: @Jonesy, Thanks for clearing that up for me. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Goal:** Print **dollar(s)** and **cent(s)** each in whole numbers. The source is an array of doubles. There is no need to change the original array itself, only read its members for display purposes.

See the [live demo](http://ideone.com/S336g8).

**Expected Output**

```
Change is as follows:
5 cents
10 cents
20 cents
50 cents
1 dollar
1 dollar and 42 cents
2 dollars
```

**Code**

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double[] coins = {0.05,0.10,0.20,0.50,1.00,1.42,2.00};

        Console.WriteLine("Change is as follows:");

        for (int j = 0; j < coins.Length; j++)
        {
            var amount = coins[j];
            var dollars = Math.Floor(amount);
            var change = amount - dollars;
            var cents = 100*change;

            string ds = dollars == 1 ? String.Empty : "s";
            string cs = cents == 1 ? String.Empty : "s";

            if (amount >= 0 && amount < 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} cents", cents);
            }
            else if (dollars >= 1 && cents == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} dollar{1}", dollars, ds);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} dollar{1} and {2} cent{3}",
                    dollars, ds, cents, cs);
            }
        }
    }
}
```